# How can I combine data from two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get `first_name` and `last_name` using uid, and get `url` from FILE_ATTACH_INFO table usign the same uid. I tried below but seems like it doesn't work because they have a different number of columns. How can I make this happen?

```
    SELECT first_name, last_name 
        FROM `USER` AS a 
        WHERE uid = '00283366-85df-4c1b-9d94-7beafb8d44fd'
UNION 
    SELECT url
        FROM `FILE_ATTACH_INFO`
        WHERE user_id = '00283366-85df-4c1b-9d94-7beafb8d44fd'
```

I'm expecting to get

```
first_name   |   last_name   |   url
------------------------------------------------
kim          |     asdf      |  https://qwef.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * FROM `USER`  a JOIN `FILE_ATTACH_INFO` b on a.uid = b.user_id WHERE a.uid = '00283366-85df-4c1b-9d94-7beafb8d44fd'
```

Try an inner join...

Comment: I tried `Select * FROM `USER` AS a JOIN `FILE_ATTACH_INFO` b on a.uid = b.user_id WHERE a.uid = '00283366-85df-4c1b-9d94-7beafb8d44fd'` and it doesn't get me any result

Comment: what's the data type for columns user_id and uid

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, b.url 
        FROM USER AS a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FILE_ATTACH_INFO b ON a.uid = b.user_id
        WHERE a.uid = '00283366-85df-4c1b-9d94-7beafb8d44fd'
```

Comment: please provide explanation why you use left join

Comment: @maSTAShuFu there's no guarantee that `b.user_id` is not null, and the OP hasn't stipulated that no rows should be returned on the case where no rows exist in `FILE_ATTACH_INFO`. I'd argue that given those unknowns, this answer is as correct as one using `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using wrong operation, you only can apply union when the columns of two tables are the same. in this case you need to join two tables on the column that they share.

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, fa.url FROM 
user  u
INNER JOIN file_attach_info  fa
  on u.uid = fa.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```html
SELECT a.first_name,a.last_name,f.url FROM USER AS a INNER JOIN FILE_ATTACH_INFO AS f ON f.user_id=a.uid WHERE 1;
```